# How to calculate rows count in where statement in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, left-join

I have two tables in SQL Server:

- `order` (columns: `order_id`, `payment_id`)
- `payment` (columns: `payment_id`, `is_pay`)

I want to get all orders with two more properties:

1. How many rows where `is_pay` is 1:

   ```
    where payment_id = <...> payment.is_pay = 1
   ```
2. And the count of the rows (without the first filter)

   ```
    select count(*) 
    from payment 
    where payment_id = <...>
   ```

So I wrote this query:

```
select 
    *, 
    (select count(1) from payment p 
     where p.payment_id = o.payment_id and p.is_pay = 1) as total 
from 
    order o
```

The problem is how to calculate the rows without the `is_pay` = 1?

I mean the "some of many"

Comment: Sample data would be helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First aggregate in `payment` and then join to `order`:

```
SELECT o.*, p.total_pay, p.total
FROM [order] o 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT payment_id, SUM(is_pay) total_pay, COUNT(*) total
  FROM payment
  GROUP BY payment_id
) p ON p.payment_id = o.payment_id;
```

Change `LEFT` to `INNER` join if all orders have at least 1 payment.
Also, if `is_pay`'s data type is `BIT`, change `SUM(is_pay)` to:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN is_pay = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a join with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    o.payment_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN p.is_pay = 1 THEN 1 END) AS pay_cnt,
    COUNT(p.payment_id) AS all_cnt
FROM "order" o
LEFT JOIN payment p
    ON o.payment_id = p.payment_id
GROUP BY
    o.payment_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join (`outer apply`) for this:

```
select o.*, p.*
from orders o outer apply
     (select count(*) as num_payments,
             sum(case when is_pay = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_payments_1
      from payments p
      where p.payment_id = o.payment_id
     ) p;
```

Note:  Assuming that `is_pay` only takes on the values of `0` and `1` (which seems reasonable given the name), you can simplify this to:

```
select o.*, p.*
from orders o outer apply
     (select count(*) as num_payments,
             sum(is_pay) as num_payments_1
      from payments p
      where p.payment_id = o.payment_id
     ) p;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for counts per payment id then use this:

```
    select 
    payment.payment_id,
    count(*) as total,
    count(case when payment.is_pay = 1 then 1 else 0) end as total_is_pay_orders
    
    from orders
    left join payment
    on orders.payment_id = payment.payment_id
group by 1
```